# why can't I get the string while scraping with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

here is my code i want to scrape a list of words from a website,
but when i call the .string on the

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.merriam-webster.com/browse/thesaurus/a"
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
entry_view = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entries'})
view = entry_view[0]
list = view.ul

for m in list:
    for x in m:
        title = x.string
        print(title)
```

what I want is a list printing the text from the website but what I get is an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vidu/PycharmProjects/untitled/hello.py", line 14, in <module>
    title = x.string
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'string'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vidu/PycharmProjects/untitled/hello.py", line 14, in <module>
    title = x.string
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Comment: did you tried to write `title = x` without .string

Comment: yes but it gives the complete output as           <a href="/thesaurus/abstain%20from">abstain from</a>           but  all i want is abstain from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using the following piece of code.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.merriam-webster.com/browse/thesaurus/a"
html_source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")

entry_view = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entries'})

entries = []
for elem in entry_view:
    for e in elem.find_all('a'):
        entries.append(e.text)

#show only 5 elements and whole list length
print(entries[:5])
print(entries[-5:])
print(len(entries))
```

**Output:**

```
['A1', 'aback', 'abaft', 'abandon', 'abandoned']
['absorbing', 'absorption', 'abstainer', 'abstain from', 'abstemious']
100
```

---

**In your code:**

```
print(type(list))
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

print(type(m))
<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>

print(type(x))
<class 'str'>
```

So, as you can see, the variable `x` is already a string, so it's non-sense to use the [bs4 method `.string()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string).

**p.s.:** you shouldn't use a variable name like `list`, it's a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'string'

This is telling you that the object is already a string. Try removing that and it should work.

It also tells you that the proper syntax of the string data type is `str` not `string`.

Another thing to take home from this is that you convert using `title = str(x)`, but since it is already a string in this case it is redundant.

To quote [Google](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings):

> Python has a built-in string class named "str" with many handy features (there is an older module named "string" which you should not use)

Comment: but it should give us a link rather than a string

Comment: In this case you should edit your question to correctly identify your request: you want to take a single word from a larger string. For that, I think regex would be the best tool

Comment: that i can do but i was curious why is it that when i try this without loops it gives correct but it gives only for the first list

Comment: `string` is an older module which should not be used, since `str` is far better. Explaining why is a different question altogether